# How can I use a secret variable in Azure Devops bash task which could be undefined

Tags: bash, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-keyvault

I am trying to create a config file using a bash task in Azure Devops. The variables come from azure keyvault, so I don't know which variables are defined and which ones are undefined.

```yaml
- script: |
    touch config.txt
    echo "1. $(MyDefinedVariable)" >> config.txt
    echo "2. $(MyUndefinedVariable)" >> config.txt
    cat config.txt
```

Since `MyUndefinedVariable` is not defined, the pipeline doesn't substitute `$(MyUndefinedVariable)`, resulting in a bash error `MyUndefinedVariable: command not found`.

I have tried using the `env` argument to use bash variables but I get the same error since "$(MyUndefinedVariable)" is being passed in to the bash environment.

```yaml
- script: |
    touch config.txt
    echo "1. $MY_DEFINED_VARIABLE" >> config.txt
    echo "2. $MY_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE" >> config.txt
    cat config.txt
  env:
    MY_DEFINED_VARIABLE: $(MyDefinedVariable)
    MY_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE: $(MyUndefinedVariable)
```

I just want undefined variables to resolve to an empty string but can't find a sensible way to do it.

Comment: How do you "not know which variables are defined and which are undefined"? That's pretty essential information.

Comment: @daniu I have some different environments with a separate keyvaults and some environments simply don't need all the secrets.
I could add empty values into keyvault for environments which don't have a value, but I am looking for a solution where an undefined value results in an empty string instead of error or unexpectedly leaving "$(UndefinedVariable)" as the value.

Comment: @Mike Monteith Not get your latest information, if the below answer is helpful, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread. Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

All variables mapped from Azure KeyVault are considered as secrets so mapping like this one is necessary:

```yaml
  env:
    MY_DEFINED_VARIABLE: $(MyDefinedVariable)
    MY_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE: $(MyUndefinedVariable)
```

I'm afraid that if you are not aware of values in your KeyVault you need to use [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/quick-create-cli) to check this. To checks all secret keys you can use [this command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/keyvault/secret?view=azure-cli-latest#az_keyvault_secret_list):

```
az keyvault secret list [--id]
                        [--maxresults]
                        [--query-examples]
                        [--subscription]
                        [--vault-name]
```

You can combine this CLI with [Azure CLI task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-cli?view=azure-devops).

Comment: Ok, so I can manually set the missing variables to an empty string this way. I had assumed there would be a simpler way to do this with the KeyVault task and separate bash script.

Comment: IMHO. Yes an no. If you know what variables you can expect, you can take all keys from key vault via cli, compare, set those which doesn't exist in key vault. But use key vault task for getting others. And remember about env mapping.